# F#: UnitTest case failled

Tags: testing, f#

Consider i have a function like `newConvert`. I am sopposed to recieve an error for  `newCovertor("IL")` . To generate this erorr: I used `failwith "Invalid Input"`

The erorr is :

```
System.Exception: Invalid Input
>    at FSI_0160.inputChecker(FSharpList`1 numberList) in C:\Users\Salman\Desktop\coursework6input\itt8060-master\coursework6input\BrokenRomanNumbers\Library1.fs:line 140
   at FSI_0160.newCovertor(String romanNumber) in C:\Users\Salman\Desktop\coursework6input\itt8060-master\coursework6input\BrokenRomanNumbers\Library1.fs:line 147
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0165>.$FSI_0165.main@() in C:\Users\Salman\Desktop\coursework6input\itt8060-master\coursework6input\BrokenRomanNumbers\newtest.fs:line 32
Stopped due to error
```

I used `FsUnit` and `Nunit`, they are loaded and installed and working rightly.
Then I made a tes for it using

```
[<TestFixture>]
type ``Given a Roman number15 ``()=



         [<Test>]
         member this.
               ``Whether the right convert for this number must be exist``()=
                  newCovertor("IL") |> should equal System.Exception
```

I cannot understand!! The function fails rightly, but the test does not accept it, so why??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`newCovertor` does not produce a `System.Execption` - it *throws* it - so you never get to the `should equal ...` part

to catch the exception with FsUnit you have to wrap it as an action:

```
(fun () -> newCovertor("IL") |> ignore) |> should throw typeof<System.Exception>
```

also see the [really good docs](https://fsprojects.github.io/FsUnit/) - there are quite a few ways to achieve this

---

The reason your version is not working is that NUnit will normaly mark a test as failed exactly when a exception is thrown inside the test-methods body - which you do.

If you wrap it in an action than the `should throw` can choose to execute this *delayed*  action inside `try ... match` block to catch the expected exception and filter it out (or in this case throw an exception if there where none)

btw: just like in C#/VB.net you can also use the [`ExpectedExceptionAttribute`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=exception&r=2.4.8) from NUnit on the method level if you like - this way the test-framework will handle it for you.